# Pandas. Выборочное обновление данных

Tags: python, pandas

Столкнулся с проблемой, хотел соединить два фрейма так, чтобы обновлялись данные по двум параметрам.

Наглядно покажу в скриншотах:

*df0:*

[image: df0]

*df1:*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хочу их соединить так, чтобы обновились данные колонок "qua" и "prise"
по параметрам "name" и "pid". Тое сть если "name" из одного фрейма равно "name"-у из другого фрейма и их pid-ы одинаковы, то нужно взять "prise", "qua" из другого фрейма и заменить в первом на том же месте.

Документацию pandas изучал, не могу додумать, как это реализовать.

Также предоставляю скриншот того, что хочу получить:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тут видно, если сравнить с прошлым *df0*, что в колонках со значением name1, name4, name5, и одинаковым pid сменились qua и prise на основе *df1*.

Более близко получился такой вариант:

```
df0[df0.pid.isin(df1.pid.values)] = df1
```

Но он не удовлетворяет требованиям, так как у меня не всегда индексы совпадают.

Comment: Данные в вопросе должны быть в воспроизводимом виде, а не скриншотами. Иначе это противоречит правилам сайта и вопрос может быть закрыт.

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе [mcve] входных данных (__в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл__) и __то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе__. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)